# Not able to append XML element in response

Tags: java, rest, jaxb

I have created a webservices which accepts XML data and after some computation over server it adds few fields in xml and returns the output to the client. I am using JAX-RS for Restful webservice and JAXB.

Now the problem is when the response is sent back to the client it doesn't include the newly upadated elemnts.

here is the code detail,

***class that represent XML (Using JAXB)***

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "market")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class IBMarketInfo {

    @XmlElement(name="contract")
    Contract m_Contract;

    @XmlElement(name="tickerId")
    int m_tickerId;

    @XmlElement(name="tickList")
    String m_genericTickList;

    @XmlElement(name="snapshot")
    boolean m_snapshot;


    @XmlElement(name="mktdata") // I AM NOT BE ABLE TO VIEW THIS ELEMENT IN THE RESPONSE
    List<String>m_Ticker;




    public IBMarketInfo(){

    }
 public void setTicker(String data){
         if (m_Ticker == null) {
                m_Ticker = new ArrayList<String>();
            }
      m_Ticker.add(data);

    }
    public List<String> getTicker(){

        if (m_Ticker == null) {
                m_Ticker = new ArrayList<String>();
            }

        return m_Ticker;
    }
    public void setTickerId(int tickerid){
        m_tickerId = tickerid;
    }
    public void setGenericTickList(String ticklist){
        m_genericTickList = ticklist;
    }
    public void setSnapshot(boolean snapshot){
        m_snapshot=snapshot;
    }
    public void setContract(Contract contract){
        m_Contract = contract;
    }
    public int getTickerId(){
            return m_tickerId;
    }
    public String getGenericTickList()    {
        return m_genericTickList;
    }
    public boolean getSnapShot(){
        return m_snapshot;
    }
    public Contract getContract(){
        return m_Contract;
    }


}
```

***Restful Webservices request function***

```
public JAXBElement<IBMarketInfo>getMarketData(JAXBElement<IBMarketInfo> info){

    MainAccess ma = new MainAccess(); // MainAccess Will pull the data from external server
    IBMarketInfo market = info.getValue(); 

   ma.onRequestData(market.getTickerId(),market.getContract(),market.getGenericTickList(),
   market.getSnapShot()); // set the user given input from xml 

  return info;
}
```

***Inside MainAccess class i am doing following***

```
 public class MainAccess {

   private IBMarketInfo m_marketInfo  = new IBMarketInfo(); //declaring in class

    // as an when data comes these following functions will add data into List
    public void tickSize( int tickerId, int field, int size) {

        String msg = EWrapperMsgGenerator.tickSize( tickerId, field, size);
        m_marketInfo.setTicker(msg); // setting m_Ticker 

    }
    public void tickPrice( int tickerId, int field, double price, int canAutoExecute) {

        String msg = EWrapperMsgGenerator.tickPrice( tickerId, field, price, canAutoExecute);

        m_marketInfo.setTicker(msg); //setting m_Ticker 

    }
}
```

i have created following Market information object and tried to set values of List in between the code

```
private IBMarketInfo m_marketInfo  = new IBMarketInfo();
 m_marketInfo.setTicker(msg);
```

***XML Request***

The problem is i am getting the same XML without appending that mktdata

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<market>
    <contract>
        <symbol>IBM</symbol>
        <sectype>STK</sectype>
        <exchange>SMART</exchange>
        <currency>USD</currency>    
    </contract> 
        <tickerId>1</tickerId>
    <tickList>1212,12121</tickList>
    <snapshot>false</snapshot>
<ticker-data></ticker-data>
</market>
```

Comment: Are you sure the m_Ticker variable is populated?  Also have you tried running a standalone example outside JAX-RS to test the mappings?

Comment: ya i am sure that m_Ticker by using  m_marketInfo.setTicker(msg);
code line which ultimately use m_Ticker. m sorry but I didn't get the second question of yours

Comment: In my answer below I have tried you model in a standalone example and everything works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in the following code.  MainAccess creates an IBMaretInfo, but you are returning the IBMarkettInfo that was passed in unmodified.

```
public JAXBElement<IBMarketInfo>getMarketData(JAXBElement<IBMarketInfo> info){

    MainAccess ma = new MainAccess(); // MainAccess Will pull the data from external server
    IBMarketInfo market = info.getValue(); 

   ma.onRequestData(market.getTickerId(),market.getContract(),market.getGenericTickList(),
   market.getSnapShot()); // set the user given input from xml 

  return info;
}
```

---

You model appears to be correctly mapping, since when I run the following code:

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception  {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(IBMarketInfo.class);

        IBMarketInfo ibmi = new IBMarketInfo();
        ibmi.setTicker("FOO");
        ibmi.setTicker("BAR");

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(ibmi, System.out);
    }

}
```

I get the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<market>
    <tickerId>0</tickerId>
    <snapshot>false</snapshot>
    <mktdata>FOO</mktdata>
    <mktdata>BAR</mktdata>
</market>
```

Comment: How would i modified it , i mean how can i reflect the change in info ?

Comment: @Hunt - It depends, do you want MainAccess to create a new IBMarketInfo?  If so you return a JAXBElement wrapping the IBMarketInfo from MainAcess.  If you want MainAccess to act on the IBMarketInfo passed in you could make MainAccess stateless and pass an IBMarketInfo as a parameter.

Comment: i got the first way , but in second one you mean to say that the input that i am receiving as a parameter in webservice request function, i pass  that IBMarketInfo info to MainAccess as an argument and modify it ?